# Again on an existence of convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a(m,n))_{m,n \in N}$  be a double sequence of positive numbers.

Suppose that we know that there exists a limit $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a(m,n)=L$. Does there always exists an increasing functions $f_1:N→N$ and $f_2:N→N$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a\left(f_1(n),f_2(n)\right)=L?$

Comment: Does $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a(m,n)=L$ imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a(m,n)$ exists for any $m$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first limit implies that for any $\epsilon$ there is an $M$ and an $N$ so that
$$|a(m,n)-L| < \epsilon$$
for $m>M$ and $n>N$. Let $\epsilon(n)$ be an arbitrary decreasing sequence of positive terms that converges to zero. For any particular $n$, we can find positive integers $M(n)$ and $N(n)$ so that
$$|a(p,q)-L| < \epsilon(n)$$
for $p\geq M(n), q\geq N(n)$. Let $M(n)$ and $N(n)$ be arbitrary sequences of such numbers. Then define 
$$f_1(p) = \sum_{1\leq n\leq p}(M(n))$$
$$f_2(p) = \sum_{1\leq n\leq p}(N(n))$$
Clearly $f_1(p), f_2(p)$ are increasing and from $N\to N$. Now, since $\epsilon(n)\to 0$, for any $\epsilon$, there is an $n$ such that
$$|a(f_1(n),f_2(n))-L|< \epsilon(n) < \epsilon$$
which implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a(f_1(n),f_2(n))= L$$

Answer (score 1):

Charlotte, I don't believe you're first assertion is true. $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a(m,n)$ is an iterated limit, meaning that first the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is evaluated,treating $m$ as a constamnt and then the $\lim_{m\to\infty}$.  Example:
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+m}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over1+m/n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}1=1.$$

On the other, hand if $m=n$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12=\frac12.$$

So, Gogi, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was an abuse of notation.

Comment: The double limit would be denoted as $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a(m,n)$.